# jQuery Validation - Error messages not disappearing after users entered corrected input

Tags: jquery

Screen capture : 
http://cangicodo.com/project/pic.png;
http://cangicodo.com/project/pic1.png

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="date" name="date" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">
.......
</form>
```

Script:

```
$( "#date" ).datepicker();
$( "#date" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd" );

$("#form1").validate({ 
    rules: {
        date: {required: true,},
    },
    messages: {
        date: {required: " 'Date' can't be blank.",},               
    },
})
```

I'm using the latest version of jquery validate plugin. It works fine with normal text input, radio, check box etc. Except the validation of datePicker text input and multiple selection input, error messages were not disappeared after user had entered corrected information. If I select again text box or select list they then disappear the message.I want to make it disappear as normal as others. Could you please give me some suggestions ?

Comment: Add some code please. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I have listed down some of my codes. the other text fields are validated perfectly. Except datePicker text field the error message was not disappeared immediately after user has selected the date. It only gone after clicked submit button.

Comment: Were you able to solve this ?